# How do you query SQL Function as IQueryable in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a t-sql table function called GetPeople. I was curious how I create an IQueryable in Entity Framework 6 so I can do a few things in LINQ on that query.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check this:

https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/

and this:

http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/04/09/support-for-store-functions-tvfs-and-stored-procs-in-entity-framework-6-1/

is explained, cheers.

Comment: Providing only URLs isn't very useful. Your answer doesn't actually provide any information and the URLs might be inaccessible one day. Would you consider modifying your answer to at least include information from the URLs and reference the URLs as your source material?

Comment: After adding that nuget package and following the instructions I get :

No EdmType found for type 'MyAssembly.Models.PeopleGridItem'.

Comment: I got it to work by correcting the model and adding the dbSet<PeopleGridItem>